# Personal diary XML formats?

Tags: xml, xsd, file-format

I would like to know what open-source standard XML formats exist for implementing all the data which may be implemented by a personal diary mobile or desktop application (with all possible features you could add already supported by such format). I've searched the internet but didn't find anything. Ideally the formats I'm after would be widely implemented and supported and allow for easy backup of diary data to a server and transfer diary data back and forth between one diary application and another. Of course, the most basic diaries will only need a subset of all the functionality supported by such an XML file format (just a list of dates each with its own plain-text notes).

The following format looks at some of the more basic feature I am looking for in an open interoperable standard XML for diaries file format implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<diary>
  <day date="2015-03-01">
    <entry categories="dream" topics="mary,lunch">
      <text>
Today I dreamt about having lunch with mary in the park. At the end I got scared and ran away.
      </text>
    </entry>
    <entry categories="storytelling idea" topics="engineering,flying">
      <text>
Today I was walking to school.  One thought that came to me was that of a flying bycicle. I came up with everything required to build one. Now I just need to find all the pieces and assemble them.
      </text>
    </entry>
  </day>
  <day date="2015-03-02">
    <entry categories="thoughts" topics="beach">
      <text>
If everybody went to the beach on the very same day, people would be sitting one on top of the other. It would be really crowded!
      </text>
      <image src="images/beach001.jpg" />
    </entry>
  </day>
</diary>
```

Comment: You can define your own, y'know.  Unless, of course, there are other software requirements that you haven't specified in your question.  XML is already a widely-supported format, even if it's a custom definition.

Comment: Yes, true, I *can* defined my own, but I would rather rely on a standard which meets software interoperability requirements. If I define my own, no other software than the software used to create the diary notes will be able to read it, and that's a real problem for me.

Comment: What other software uses diary notes?  Answer that question, and you'll probably have your format.  Otherwise, this is just hypothetical, since both your and my Google Search seemed to turn up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find a dedicated diary standard, consider using a standard XML format for calendars:

- [xCal](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6321) (RFC-6321) is the XML format for iCalendar.
- [WS-Calendar](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-calendar/ws-calendar/v1.0/ws-calendar-1.0-spec.html) is OASIS's standard calendar format.

You could use description or note fields for the diary entries, and interoperability would be greater than for a proprietary diary format.

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes for your answer. Now that I think about it, a diary is indeed just a cut-down version of a calendar: one or more entries per day, with each entry having one or more user-defined tags associated with it, and of course since a personal diary will be mostly narrative (memories, storytellings, feelings, thoughts, dreams, secrets could be some of the tags used) rather than focusing on scheduling meaningless appointments and times, the calendar XML format used for times will be irrelevant (and any time used by the user will be embedded in the text).

Comment: Also, users will want to have a separate (perhaps stronger) password to protect their diary (which might warrant the creation of a separate account). Personal diaries are private in nature and never shared. What is not clear to me is, whether the calendar formats you describe allow for images to be referenced (as files stored separately). Perhaps Google calendar has support for custom tasks, but the images would have to be stored in Google Drive (or perhaps in Google Picasa Web or DropBox where even more storage space would be available, and such cloud storage location could be configured)?

Comment: Perhaps besides the aforementioned entry type tags which describe the type of entry (thoughts, ideas, dreams, etc...) where some system-defined values could be supplied which can then be augmented, it could be reasonable for a diary to keep separate entry topic tags (e.g. aboutmary, rinocerouses, kansas, etc...).

Comment: At the risk of diverging too far from q/a protocol here, I'll go one last round on some of the topics you mentioned:  It might be hard to extend xCal via XML, but you could invent your own way to annotate its `description` (`xsd:string` only) content.  OTOH, WS-Calendar's `artifact` is of `ArtifactType`, which is [based](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-calendar/ws-calendar-spec/v1.0/cs01/xsd/iCalendar-wscal-extensions.xsd) on `xsd:any`, so you could extend it with XML per your diary needs.  Passwords are the province of software and systems, not XML formats.   Hope this helped.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you once again, your comments were also very useful. If you don't mind (and I hope you won't), allow me to ask you one further question. What formats does the Google Calendar API support (perhaps some proprietary XML and JSON file formats?), and are there any open source libraries which will allow you to convert back and forth from the `xCal` and `WS-Calendar` formats and the ones supported by `Google Calendar`?

Comment: @JohnHigginstyne: Sorry, but it seems I'm encouraging additional off-topic requests more than I should be.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Thanks and good luck.